# invalid covariant return type error

Tags: c++, inheritance, tree

I am getting the below error on overriding a Base Class function in the Derived Class.

```
./inc/rbtree.h:16:18: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual RBNode* RBTree::get_root()’
./inc/tree.h:25:24: error:   overriding ‘virtual Node* Tree::get_root()’
```

rbtree.h

```
class RBNode;

class RBTree: public Tree
{
    protected:
    public:
        RBTree();
        RBNode *root;
        RBNode * get_root();
        void insert_into_tree();
        //void delete_from_tree();
};
```

and the tree.h is as below

```
class Node;

class Tree
{
    protected:
        Node * root;
        list<int> treedata;
    public:
        Tree();
        /* This is where it gives error */
        virtual Node * get_root();
        void set_root(Node *root_node);
        void insert_into_tree();
        void delete_from_tree();
        void print_tree();
};
```

More Info: RBNode is derived from Node.
Now , I read this [article](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html) and it says perfectly alright to override a Base Class function to return a Derived type instace.

I searched on SO as well, but the questions regarding this didn't help much. Why is failing if it is allowed in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are forward-declaring RBNode. When the compiler sees RBTree, it doesn't yet know that RBNode is a Node.

Comment: but it is giving error in the get_root() function.

Comment: @rohit: It still doesn't know by that point.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. its clear now. RBTree is not aware of the fact that RBNode is derived from Node. Hence we have to include the header itself.

Comment: But if I remove the forward declaration, I get the below error. error: ‘RBNode’ does not name a type

Comment: @rohit: Removing the declaration means the compiler now doesn't know about RBNode at all. You have to define it, `class RBNode : public Node { … }`, ahead of the definition of RBTree.

Comment: But that definition is part of rbnode.h and I have included it.

Comment: Whatever you did, you didn't end up defining RBNode before RBTree. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @rohit It has nothing to do with your problem. You are overriding base class' virtual function with function, that declares different result type. Forward declaration of `RBNode` is required (if you do not `#include` its header).

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: C++ allows this. It's called covariant return types.